# the public vs public

Tags: articles

When should I put "the" in front of "public" ?

> (**The**) public threatened the security guy in order to go across the restricted area.

what is the role of "the" here ?

Thanks.

Comment: http://buzzmachine.com/2010/05/08/confusing-a-public-with-the-public/ fun to read!

Comment: Just change it to 'people'; especially as you're starting with the rather formal 'public' then transitioning straight to hipster with 'guy' *then* right back to formal with 'in order to access'. Stick to one style. 'people' & 'guard' will do.

Answer (score 7):

In the case of the example sentence you posted

> (the) public threatened the security guy in order to go across the restricted area.

The **The** is definitely necessary there.

In that case, you are using public as a noun. So anytime you use public as a noun, it needs ***the*** in front of it.

The times you don't need to use ***the*** in front of public is when you use public as an adjective.

For example

> Public bathrooms are often not clean, smelly, and scary.

In this case, public is an adjective describing what type of bathrooms you are referring to. You may also use ***the*** in front of the adjective public, but it is not necessary.

Not sure if the above rules are 100% correct all of the time, but I haven't been able to think of any counter examples to it.